# Relation between foreign and primary key?

Tags: sql

For example:

**Table 1**:

```
user_ID - 
username -
first_name -
email -
```

**Table 2**:

```
message_ID - 
user_ID - 
message_title -
message_body -
```

As you can see I have `user_ID` as primary key in `table 1`, and as foreign key in the second table.

If I enter 2 rows into the first table, eg.

```
1, undergz, sarah, sarah@hotmail.com
2, michel21, michaele, michalzost@gmail.com
```

And now, michaele enters the message, and I now I add this to table 2:

```
1, 2, hello, hello everybody,
```

I added this entry in the table 2 considering first table, I added `user_ID` number the same as in the `table 1`.

I did this from `$_SESSION['user_ID']` variable, when I entered the second query. So it was like

```
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES (NULL, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, '$title','$message')
```

My question is, is this the right way to do this? We define foreign key in table so we enter data STRICTLY according to primary key, it must be the same for all values?

Comment: "As you can see I have user_ID as primary key in table 1, and as foreign key in the second table" -- I can see there are attributes of the same name in both tables but this does not prove the existence of a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. Have you created a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint? You need to tell us, we can't see your SQL DDL.

Comment: no I didn't create FOREIGN KEY explicitly. Do I need to? If I just link all tables with data in order I enter it, is that enough?

Comment: Short answer: yes, you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you should ask yourself is:

*Can a row in the `table 2` exist without a corresponding row in the `table 1`?*

If the answer to your question is "no", then you need the FOREIGN KEY (a.k.a. [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)) constraint from `table 2` ("child") to `table 1` ("parent"). You can think of it as having a "pointer" from one row to another, where the DBMS itself **guarantees** you can never have a "dangling" pointer.

The "parent" set of columns in the FOREIGN KEY must always be the key, be it primary or alternate (a.k.a. UNIQUE). The "child" can be any column or combination of columns, whether they are part of a key or not. You can think of that as the parent's key columns being propagated to the child, and depending on *where* the propagated columns end up, you can have the following 2 kinds of relationships:

### 1) "Identifying" Relationship

The parent key becomes a part of the child key (so parent "helps" identify the child):

[image: identifying relationship] or [image: identifying relationship]

This models either 1:N or 1:1 relationship.

### 2) "Non-Identifying" Relationship

The parent key does **not** become the part of the child's key:

[image: non-identifying relationship]

This models 1:N relationship, but requires `message_ID` to be unique on its own (instead of in combination with `user_ID`).

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a FOREIGN KEY constraint as part of the table
> definition when you create a table. If a table already exists, you can
> add a FOREIGN KEY constraint, provided that the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> is linked to an existing PRIMARY KEY constraints or UNIQUE constraint
> in another, or the same, table. A table can contain multiple FOREIGN
> KEY constraints.
>
> If a FOREIGN KEY constraint already exists, you can modify or delete
> it. For example, you may want the FOREIGN KEY constraint of the table
> to reference other columns. However, you cannot change the length of a
> column that is defined with a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

So, you can only had values in `table2` with a `user_ID` that is already present in `table1`.

---

Regarding your question(s):

> My question is, is this the right way to do this?

It seems that yes.

> We define foreign key in table so we enter data STRICTLY according to primary key

Correct

> it must be the same for all values?

It depends, it must be a value that already exists in `table1`. In your case, for each login (user), the value should be from that user. But if you login with another, the value should be the id from that user.

Comment: I agree, the thing I needed to check is that entering all values in foreign key is on all developer, the database doesn't make difference between foreign key and primary key. If I skip to enter foreign key, it will remain NULL value, and won't be automatically field right?

Comment: Yes, you have to put the value. In the insertion the database doesn't assign it automatically.

Comment: A foreign key isn't a "field", it's a constraint on one or more columns of a table to make their values refer to existing values in another table. It doesn't have to refer to a primary key in the other table (it can be `unique`).